# Detect broken image when using hydrate instead of render from react-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-dom

We are using `hydrate` from `react-dom` in a project and are having a hard time detecting broken image links. These images come from a 3rd party API so we have no way of knowing which links work beforehand.

```
export default class Image extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <img
        src={this.props.src}
        onError={(e) => {  
          e.target.src='https://mycdn.com/fallback.jpg';
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

The above code works if we use `render` instead of `hydrate`. Is there a way to detect broken images when using `hydrate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `ReactDOM.hydrate` does not attach the `onLoad` or `onError` events.

The best method I can think of is doing a sort of 2-pass rendering. From the server, always render the fallback (or a placeholder) image. On the client, use `componentDidMount` and state to update the image's `src` to the real source.

```
export default class Image extends PureComponent {
  state = { isMounted: false }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isMounted: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <img
        src={ isMounted ? this.props.src : this.props.fallbackSrc }
        onError={(e) => {  
          e.target.src = this.props.fallbackSrc;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Since the server doesn't call the `componentDidMount` lifecycle, it will always render the fallback image.

After the `hydrate` completes and the component is mounted, it will update the state triggering a rerender that will then use the real `src` from props.